# Custom toolbar in C# windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

I'm trying to create a toolbar/menu as in the image below.

[image: Toolbar Image]

I've added a toolstrip control. It has some buttons with images and text below. But I don't know how to reproduce the "grouped" look in the image above.

Does someone have an idea how to do that?

Comment: Please correct the misleading title!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The control in your image is a *ribbon* (not a *toolbar*, *toolstrip* or *tooltip*).

WinForms doesn't support ribbons out of the box. But it looks like there are ribbon controls available, such as [RibbonWinForms on GitHub](https://github.com/RibbonWinForms/RibbonWinForms).

Comment: Oh, I thought that is something like a toolstrip. I will check the link, thank you :)